# How to put series and number at the end of reference and between parentheses

Tags: biblatex

The bibliographic instructions of my faculty want the series and number to be placed at the end of the reference, in parentheses, **without the comma before the first parenthesis** (this is the hard part). I've already managed to put the series and number at the end of the reference by redefining the book driver of the `standard.bbx`, but I can't manage to put them in parentheses **and** remove the comma before the first parenthesis.

In other words...

- The MWE gives this : CHAUCER Geoffrey, The book title, 2nd édition, London : Scrooge Editions, 2020, Collection 124.
- I would like this : CHAUCER Geoffrey, The book title, 2nd édition, London : Scrooge Editions, 2020 (Collection 124). → Parentheses, no comma after the 2020

Here is the MWE (I compile with xelatex) :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad3]{biblatex}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\begin{filecontents}{bibdata.bib}
@book{livre,
        author = {Geoffrey Chaucer},
        title = {The book title},
        edition = {2nd édition},
        location = {London},
        publisher = {Scrooge Editions},
        year = {2020},
        series = {Collection},
        number = {124}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{bibdata.bib}
\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}[0]{\addcomma\addspace}
\renewcommand{\revsdnamepunct}{\addspace} 
\renewcommand{\subtitlepunct}[0]{\adddot\addspace} 
\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}% I inteverted "publisher+location+date" and "series+number"
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}


\begin{document}
Filling text\autocite{livre}
\end{document}
```

Does anybody know how this could be done ? I'm not a LaTeX expert and I just started understanding how biblatex macros work, so if you use a new command, please explain to me what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get parentheses around several fields at once (like series *and* number) you can use `\printtext[parens]{...}`, but then we need to avoid printing an empty pair of parentheses in case there is no series (I'm assuming a `number` can only occur with a `series`), so we need to check if there is no `series` with `\iffieldundef{series}` and do nothing in that case.

```
\renewbibmacro*{series+number}{%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \printfield{series}%
       \setunit*{\addspace}%
       \printfield{number}}%
     \newunit}}
```

The default definition of that macro can be found in [`standard.bbx` (ll. 853-857 in v3.14)](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/2ddd2836927d08ac600c8fa3af1897417548ac05/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx#L853-L857).

If you wanted to check for `series` and `number`, because you can have an entry with empty `series` field and non-empty `number` field, one would normally use `etoolbox`'s `\ifboolexpr` to combine two tests. When tests are used in `\ifboolexpr` they are wrapped in a pair of curly braces and prefixed with the keyword `test`. Inside `\ifboolexpr` you can use the logical operators `and`, `or` and `not` and you can use parentheses for grouping.

```
\renewbibmacro*{series+number}{%
  \ifboolexpr{    test {\iffieldundef{series}}
              and test {\iffieldundef{number}}}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \printfield{series}%
       \setunit*{\addspace}%
       \printfield{number}}%
     \newunit}}
```

Then it's just a matter of re-ordering the macro calls in the bibliography driver. The best order depends on the exact output you want in case your entries have more fields (`note`, `isbn`, `pages`, ...), I chose a slightly different position than the one in the MWE, but that was just my gut feeling.

Note that something similar will probably have to be done for the `@collection`, `@proceedings`, `@inbook`, `@incollection` and `@inproceedings` drivers (and possibly `@manual` and `@dataset` as well).

In order to get only a space before the parentheses containing series and number we replace the `\newunit\newblock` before it with `\setunit{\addspace}`. `\newunit\newblock` inserts the punctuation from `\newunitpunct` and a block marker (which may or may not do something, depending on the setting of the `block` option), `\setunit{\addspace}` just prints a space instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad3]{biblatex}

\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\renewcommand{\subtitlepunct}{\addperiod\space}

\renewcommand{\revsdnamepunct}{}

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{default}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}

\renewbibmacro*{series+number}{%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \printfield{series}%
       \setunit*{\addspace}%
       \printfield{number}}%
     \newunit}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{livre,
  author    = {Geoffrey Chaucer},
  title     = {The Book Title},
  edition   = {2},
  location  = {London},
  publisher = {Scrooge Editions},
  year      = {2020},
  series    = {Collection},
  number    = {124},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Filling text\autocite{livre}
\end{document}
```

[image: Chaucer Geoffrey, The Book Title, 2 e éd., London : Scrooge Editions, 2020 (Collection 124).]

---

Note that I replaced your

```
\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}[0]{\addcomma\addspace}
\renewcommand{\revsdnamepunct}{\addspace} 
\renewcommand{\subtitlepunct}[0]{\adddot\addspace}
```

with

```
\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\renewcommand{\subtitlepunct}{\addperiod\space}

\renewcommand{\revsdnamepunct}{}
```

If you are already using one `\add...` command, the following `\addspace` can be replaced by `\space`. `\addspace` just does some additional housekeeping here that is not needed because the previous `\add...` command will have done it already. The usual `biblatex` idiom is therefore `\addcomma\space` and not `\addcomma\addspace`.

`\adddot` inserts an abbreviation dot (i.e. a dot in an abbreviation like "i.e.") whereas `\addperiod` inserts a sentence-ending period/full stop. Usually `\addperiod` is what you use as punctuation between fields. `\adddot` is only needed for abbreviations. One noticable difference between the two is that `biblatex` capitalises after `\addperiod` but not after `\adddot`.

`\revsdnamepunct` need not produce a space, since the space is already implicit in the name format via `\bibnamedelimd`. This can be seen by the fact that the default definition `\newcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{\addcomma}` from `biblatex.def` also does not inserts a space.

I also dropped the `[0]` because I think it just adds noise here.

As for the name formats I think the order

```
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{default}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}
```

that I used is slightly more natural. But it will produce exactly the same result as your definition.